# Ignore folder from url path in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to ignore folder from a url path like
original url - https://example.com/dir1/dir2/1/asd to
required url - https://example.com/dir1/dir2/asd.php
but endpoint is not fixed

I have tried this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dir1/dir2/asd.php [L,QSA]
```

but this is fixing the end point and always getting hit on same file

Comment: Which part(s) of this do you need to be variable - just the `asd` at the end, or the `dir1` and/or `dir2` parts as well?

Comment: asd only and add .php, also want to remove directory after dir2 and

Comment: Try something like `RewriteRule dir1/dir2/[^/]+/(.*)$ /dir1/dir2/$1.php [L,QSA]` - `[^/]+` for an arbitrary amount of non-slash characters after the `dir1/dir2/` part, and then `(.*)` to capture anything after that. And `$1` to insert that captured value into the substitution.

Comment: Its not working its returning 404

Comment: Where is the .htaccess file located? Do you have other rules in there? What exact URL are you requesting?

Comment: its in the dir2 directory there are no other rule exact url https://anirudh-bhati-sh.webkul.com/shopify-mp/UniCommerce/1/authToken?username=asdffg&password=asdfg

Comment: _"ts in the dir2 directory"_ - then the prefix up to that of course does not need to be matched. Try just `^[^/]+/(.*)$` for the pattern then.